# Question on different parametrizations of the same curve

Tags: calculus, curves, parametrization

Let $\;σ:[0, 2\pi) \rightarrow \mathbb R^2\;$ be a curve such that $\;σ(t)=(\cos t,\sin t)\;$. It is known $\;σ\;$ represents the unit circle. However if I have $\;σ(t-1)=(\cos (t-1),\sin (t-1))\;$ then $\;σ\;$ continues to represent the unit circle.

I'm having hard time to understand where is the difference between these two curves. To be more specific, **what is happening when the angle changes?** I believe a plot would make it easier but I don't know how to make it...

Generally if $\;σ:\mathbb R \supset \mathcal I \rightarrow \mathbb R^n\;$ be a curve, then **what exactly is the difference between $\;σ(t)\;$ and $\;σ(t-t_0)\;$?** Could somebody claim that $\;σ(t-t_0)\;$ is a "translation" of $\;σ(t)\;$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, if you set, say, $t=0$, the initial point in both circles are different from each other, no?

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician Yes it's different but what does that mean? I'm sorry, I don't get it

Comment: They're two different ways of drawing the same circle. If you've ever used a [compass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass_(drawing_tool)), it's as if one starts drawing the circle by having the compass be parallel to the edge of the paper, and the other has the compass start slightly tilted.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician So the graph of $\;σ\;$ will be the same eventually but the initial point will be different. Could I claim that $\;σ(t-t_0)\;$ is a "translation" of  $\;σ(t)\;$ in that sense?

Comment: More accurate to say (only for this case) that one circle is a *rotated* version of the other.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician Ok I understood that. But for the general case?

Comment: Just say it's a reparametrization.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician Hmm.. Ok, thank you!

Comment: @kaithkolesidou This can probably better understood with a little physics: imagine $\;\sigma(t)\;$ expresses the location where a particle at time $\;t\;$ . Then, $\;\sigma(t)\,,\,\,\sigma(t-t_0)\;$ are different "places" where the particle is located at the same time (say, at time zero: $\;\sigma(0)\;,\;\;\sigma(t_0)\;$ .

Comment: @DonAntonio This kind of answer I was hoping for.. Your comment helped me a lot! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If
$$\sigma:\quad[a,b]\to{\mathbb R}^2,\qquad t\mapsto\bigl(x(t),y(t)\bigr)$$
is a parametric representation of a curve in the plane then $\tilde\sigma(\tau):=\sigma(\tau-t_0)$ is defined not on the $t$-interval $[a,b]$, but on the $\tau$-interval $[a+t_0,b+t_0]$. The two maps $\sigma$ and $\tilde\sigma$ represent the same curve. Physically one may interpret the difference between the the two representations as a time shift.

Admissible reparametrizations are strictly increasing continuous  (preferentially $C^1$) "rescaling of time" maps $$\psi:\quad[\alpha,\beta]\to[a,b],\qquad \tau\mapsto t=\psi(\tau)\ .$$ 
In particular beginning and end point of a curve, as well as "unit tangent vectors in the forward direction" stay the same.